# Why the scnr.nextLine() doesn't work in the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

[image]Hello,
I have this assignment

Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Quit", "quit", or "q" for the line of text.

And this is my code

[image]

it keeps getting me this error

[image]

I honestly don't know what I did wrong. Please help!

Answer (score -1):

your for loop is wrong, should be:

```java
for (i = userString.length() - 1; i>=0; --i) {
            System.out.print(userString.charAt(i));
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.println("input next");
                userString = scnr.nextLine();
                i = userString.length();
                if(userString.equals("Quit") || userString.equals("quit") || userString.equals("q")) break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: no it didn't work. same error. and when I used my code without the userString = scnr.nextLine() within the for loop, it worked for the first string. Like if i input "hello there", it did come out as " ereht olleh". I just can't get it to input the next string.

Comment: sorry, I type wrong, `i = userString.length() -1` , it works this time